# How to display empty XML tag in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a requirement of exporting my data into a XML format. For simplicity, consider that I have a table **Employee** with FName,MName and LName columns. To export the data into XML, I have written the following query

`SELECT  FName, MName, LName from Employee FOR XML PATH ('Emp Details'), ROOT ('Details');`

This return the data in correct XML format. However, if there is any row with `NULL` value, it skips the XML tag for that column. Like in following example MName had a `NULL` value therefore the tag for MName was missing in the XML as well:-

```
<Emp Details>
  <Details>
    <FName>Rohit</Fname>
    <LName>Kumar</LName>
  </Details>
</Emp Details>
```

I have tried using `ELEMENTS XSINIL` method but it displays the tag like

```
<MName xsi:nil="true" />
```

however, I want it to be displayed as

```
<MName />
```

Is it possible to display the `NULL` value XML tags in such a manner?
Thanks

Comment: Use `''` instead, that'll force the node to be displayed. So `ISNULL(MName,'')` would force the node to appear, but blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, wrap the value with `ISNULL` to return a blank string:

```sql
SELECT Fname,
       LName,
       ISNULL(MName,'') AS MName
FROM (VALUES('Rohit','Kumar',NULL))V(FName,LName,MName)
FOR XML PATH('Details'),ROOT('EmpDetails'); --Nodes can't have spaces in their names
```

This returns the below XML:

```xml
<EmpDetails>
    <Details>
        <Fname>Rohit</Fname>
        <LName>Kumar</LName>
        <MName></MName>
    </Details>
</EmpDetails>
```

*Note that SQL Server does not generate blank nodes using the shorter syntax, it will explicitly open and close the tags.*

Comment: Thanks, its working now. But can we restrict the empty tag as ```<MName/>```. Although I believe, XML considers both the same.

Comment: @Kartikeya I address that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an empty `MName` element in the result, just convert the NULL value to an empty string in the select statement:

```
SELECT  FName, coalesce(MName, '') as MName, LName
from Employee
FOR XML PATH ('Emp Details'), ROOT ('Details');
```

`coalesce` is the ANSI standard way of converting NULL  values to something, SQL Server accepts this as well as the SQL Server specific `IsNull`.